# how to display a dialog box over a cell on a table at on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a table of data that can be edited by clicking on each row and popping up a dialog box, I 've been trying with bootstrap modal but I'd really like that the dialog would display align with the row when I click.

Comment: What have you tried? We're not a code writing service. Please post the specific problem you are having, not your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea just to get you started.

Open the Code Snippet and run it, then hover over the MoreData column.

Basically, you can use jQuery's `.closest()` method to identify which `<tr>` of the table you are on, and then use `.offset().top` to get the vertical position in the window - and place your dialog there.

```js
$('tr td').hover(
  function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    showMdl($this); 
  },
  function(){ hideMdl(); }
);

function showMdl($this){
  var tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var os = tr.offset().top;
  $('#msg').css({'top':os+'px'}).html(os).show();
}

function hideMdl(){
  $('#msg').hide();
}
```

```css
#spacer_div{width:100vw;height:30vh;background:palegreen;}
  .flx{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;}
td{border:1px solid #ccc;}

#msg{display:none;position:fixed;left:0;top:15vh;background:wheat;z-index:2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="spacer_div" class="flx">Some Data</div>
<table>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Dummy data</td><td class="dodlg">More data9</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="msg"></div>
```